# mysql_fetch_assoc not fetching data

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently trying to pass the genre of a movie but I am getting the following errors:

> Notice: Undefined index: id_genre in --- on line 34
>
> Notice: Undefined index: id_genre in --- on line 35
>
> Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id_genre' at row 1

```
$genre  = ($_POST['genre']);
$genre_match = mysql_query("SELECT genre FROM genre WHERE genre='$genre'")or die(mysql_error());
$row_genre_match = mysql_fetch_assoc($genre_match);
$genre_id = $row_genre_match['id_genre'];
$insert_genre = mysql_query("INSERT INTO film_genre (`id_film` , `id_genre`) VALUES ('$fid','$genre_id')")or die(mysql_error());
```

int(41) string(1) "6"

Comment: `genre_match ` is used as a constant in this context, but constant's cannot be modified, therefore the query fails, so the fetch assoc fails, so the index cannot be grabbed from a failed result. Those can't be the only errors.. Also, please stop using `mysql_` as it's deprecated and will be removed in newer versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `SELECT` not return `id_genre`

```
$genre_match = mysql_query("SELECT id_genre FROM genre WHERE genre='$genre'")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Cheers that seemed to fix that problem however the data is still not being added into the table but I am getting no errors.

Comment: @Nic Check the values ​​of variables $fid and $genre_id. Give a var_dump to check. INSERT are coming in correctly?

Comment: The results where int(41) string(1) "6" I think the problem may be that genre_id is a int not a string.

Comment: @Nic Use $genre_id = (int) $row_genre_match['id_genre']; .Verify your structure database.

Comment: it is now being passed as an int but still not going in the table. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Yes thank you , having problems with an update query now though .

Comment: @Nic If you can accept the answer and post a new question for you to help.